# Refactoring code for automation with Selenium

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver, assert

While automating the test script, I've been trying to refactor / extract a method from this line:

```
assertEquals("Enter your password.", textError);
```

the result being:

```
public void assertEquals() {
    assertEquals("Enter your password.", textError);
}
```

When I give it a parameter:

```
public void assertEquals(String textValue) {
    assertEquals(textValue, textError);
}
```

I receive an error:

> The method assertEquals(String) in the type LoginPageTests is not
>   applicable for the arguments (String, String)

And when I add the second `String`:

```
public void assertEquals(String textValue, String textError) {
   ...
}
```

tests fail.

What's my problem, please?

Here's the entire class:

```
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import com.thoughtworks.selenium.*;

public class LoginPageTests {
    private static Selenium selenium;
    LoginPage loginPage = new LoginPage(selenium);

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUp() throws Exception {
        selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*chrome",
                "http://gmail.com/");
        selenium.start();
        selenium.windowMaximize();
        selenium.open("/");
    }

    @Test
    // correct login, no pwd
    public void TestMethod0() throws Exception {
        loginPage.typeEmail("111");
        loginPage.typePwd("");
        loginPage.submit();

        assertTrue(loginPage.countError() > 0);

        loginPage
                .getText("//span[@id='errormsg_0_Passwd' and @class='error-msg']");
        assertEquals("Enter your password.", loginPage.textError);
    }

    @Test
    // correct login, wrong pwd OR wrong login, correct pwd
    public void TestMethod1() throws Exception {
        loginPage.typeEmail("222");
        loginPage.typePwd("foo");
        loginPage.submit();

        loginPage
                .getText("//span[@id='errormsg_0_Passwd' and @class='error-msg']");
        assertEquals("The email or password you entered is incorrect. ?",
                loginPage.textError);
    }

    @Test
    // no login, correct pwd
    public void TestMethod2() throws Exception {
        loginPage.typeEmail("");
        loginPage.typePwd("foo");
        loginPage.submit();

        loginPage
                .getText("//span[@id='errormsg_0_Email' and @class='error-msg']");
        assertEquals("Enter your email address.", loginPage.textError);
    }

    @Test
    // no login, no pwd
    public void TestMethod3() throws Exception {
        loginPage.typeEmail("");
        loginPage.typePwd("");
        loginPage.submit();

        loginPage
                .getText("//span[@id='errormsg_0_Email' and @class='error-msg']");
        assertEquals("Enter your email address.", loginPage.textError);
    }

    @Test
    // correct login, correct pwd
    public void TestMethod4() throws Exception {
        loginPage.typeEmail("111");
        loginPage.typePwd("foo");
        loginPage.submit();

        assertTrue(loginPage.countError() == 0);
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDown() throws Exception {
        selenium.stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the entire file ? I'd like to see your imports and where you defined textError.

Comment: Expanded it in the question's body. Thanks.

Comment: Imports seem to be ok. Where is assertEquals(String) defined ? In LoginPageTests or in another class that has to be imported/extended ?

Comment: assertEquals(String) comes from org.junit.Assert.*; I didn't define it.

Comment: Why dont you use junit assertEquals directly? Trying to re-define/write your own assertEquals donot give any value.

Comment: @Nguyen Vu Hoang: As you might see, I use it directly; it's just the tutorial I'm following advises to refactor all methods that expose how the actual page works (Xpath etc.) and put them in a separate class.

Comment: @dmeps you made me confused, in your question, you mentioned you refactor junit assertEquals into public void assertEquals() { } --> You need to override/overload junit.assertEquals

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the example refactoring that you posted, your problem is that you are attempting to redefine an existing method, without correctly [overloading](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html) it. This is evident in the error message

> The method assertEquals(String) in the type LoginPageTests is not applicable for the arguments (String, String)

You can see that the refactored `assertEquals(String)` method which you are defining is in conflict with the existing `assertEquals(String, String)` method that you call within it.

You can remedy this by defining your method with a different name, or overloading it, which will allow two methods with the same name, but different signatures:

```
@Overload
public void assertEquals(String textValue) {
    assertEquals(textValue, textError);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but why, upon refactoring, I do receive a red underline to the method in Eclipse? Why the extraction goes awry?

Comment: Upon looking at this a second time, I'm confused as to what you're trying to achieve. It looks like you're trying to treat `assertEquals()` as an `Exception`, rather than checking whether your program's behaviour matches what is expected. If there a use case where the `textError` field will be equal to the string "Enter your password."?

Comment: @ voidHead: Yes, there IS such a case! As per comment in the code, if you enter your username in Gmail's login page, you have the very string "Enter your password."

Comment: Right, just checking. Did you try simply overloading the method, or changing its name? I think redefining a well-established method is a poor idea in the first place, as it introduces ambiguity to your code.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks, guys! Looks like I was totally wrong when I tried to re factor the assertion, whereas, in fact, it handles the input, not the page inner works. What I eventually did, was I got rid of the first of two elements in the getText() method and received its common denominator which allowed me to extract the method and move it to the class that has all the extracted methods.